# YaccLexTools: Gplex - how to make it case insensitive

Tags: c#, yacc, lex

I am using latest version of YaccLexTools (0.2.2) which include GPLEX 1.2.1.

I am trying to define a token which would be case-insensitive.

However it does not seem to be an easy task. None of the default solutions work:
1. Putting %option caseless - GPLEX does not understand it.
2. Using Regex ?i: option does not work either. E.g. 
`Second         (?i:(s|sec|second)
 Seconds        (?i:seconds)`

At the moment I am using a really mundane workaround:

```
Seconds         ([sS][eE][cC][oO][nN][dD][sS])
```

But long-term this seems to be not feasible or rather not practical solution.

Is there any *proper* way to make GPLEX case insensitive either globally or per token?

Thanks, Radek

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that works. It applies case insensitivity globally. It is a bit hacky but so far that's the only that works.

You need to edit your csproj file manually.

1. Find the lines that start with:

   `<Exec Command="$(GplexTool) &quot;/out:`
2. Add string `&quot;/caseInsensitive&quot;` right after `$(GplexTool)` as follows:

   `<Exec Command="$(GplexTool) &quot;/caseInsensitive&quot; &quot;/out:`
3. Repeat it for all occurrences.
4. Rebuild the project.

That should do the trick.